# Octave imwrite writes a blank image from a tridimensional matrix

Tags: image, octave

I'm still learning octave, and i need to use the imwrite function.

My program basically just needs to read an image, then create a smaller matrix to reduce the original image (i'm not trying to interpolate, just getting points at specific lines and columns).

Here are some examples of my input and output matrices

```
Original
ans(:,:,1) =

  184  175  184  194  194  194  194  194  184  194  194  194  194  194  184  150
  184  184  175  175  150  159  175  184  184  184  175  175  184  184  159  159
  175  184  184  184  175  184  175  159  159  159  159  175  175  184  184  150
  150  126  126  150  150  126  103  103  126  126  103  126  103  103  126  103
  184  194  159  194  194  194  194  159  194  194  194  184  175  175  159  184
  175  184  184  175  159  175  159  150  159  175  175  184  184  184  184  175
  159  159  175  184  175  175  175  150  184  184  184  175  175  159  159  159
  103  103  126  126  150  126  103  103  103  103  126  126  126  150  126  103
  184  194  194  184  175  175  194  194  194  194  194  194  194  194  184  159
  184  175  184  184  184  184  175  159  159  159  175  159  175  159  159  150
  194  184  175  175  159  159  159  159  175  175  175  175  159  159  184  159
  103  103  126  150  150  126  103  103  103  126  150  126  126  103  103  103
  194  159  184  194  194  184  184  159  194  194  194  159  194  184  194  194
  175  175  184  184  159  159  175  159  159  184  184  175  184  175  175  175
  175  159  159  175  184  175  159  150  184  184  175  159  159  159  159  159
  103  126  126  103  103  126  150  150  150  126  103  126  103  103  103  103

ans(:,:,2) =

  148  143  148  157  157  157  157  157  148  157  157  157  157  157  148  116
  148  148  143  143  116  132  143  148  148  148  143  143  148  148  132  132
  143  148  148  148  143  148  143  132  132  132  132  143  143  148  148  116
  116   98   98  116  116   98   80   80   98   98   80   98   80   80   98   80
  148  157  132  157  157  157  157  132  157  157  157  148  143  143  132  148
  143  148  148  143  132  143  132  116  132  143  143  148  148  148  148  143
  132  132  143  148  143  143  143  116  148  148  148  143  143  132  132  132
   80   80   98   98  116   98   80   80   80   80   98   98   98  116   98   80
  148  157  157  148  143  143  157  157  157  157  157  157  157  157  148  132
  148  143  148  148  148  148  143  132  132  132  143  132  143  132  132  116
  157  148  143  143  132  132  132  132  143  143  143  143  132  132  148  132
   80   80   98  116  116   98   80   80   80   98  116   98   98   80   80   80
  157  132  148  157  157  148  148  132  157  157  157  132  157  148  157  157
  143  143  148  148  132  132  143  132  132  148  148  143  148  143  143  143
  143  132  132  143  148  143  132  116  148  148  143  132  132  132  132  132
   80   98   98   80   80   98  116  116  116   98   80   98   80   80   80   80

ans(:,:,3) =

   95   85   95   98   98   98   98   98   95   98   98   98   98   98   95   65
   95   95   85   85   65   77   85   95   95   95   85   85   95   95   77   77
   85   95   95   95   85   95   85   77   77   77   77   85   85   95   95   65
   65   55   55   65   65   55   44   44   55   55   44   55   44   44   55   44
   95   98   77   98   98   98   98   77   98   98   98   95   85   85   77   95
   85   95   95   85   77   85   77   65   77   85   85   95   95   95   95   85
   77   77   85   95   85   85   85   65   95   95   95   85   85   77   77   77
   44   44   55   55   65   55   44   44   44   44   55   55   55   65   55   44
   95   98   98   95   85   85   98   98   98   98   98   98   98   98   95   77
   95   85   95   95   95   95   85   77   77   77   85   77   85   77   77   65
   98   95   85   85   77   77   77   77   85   85   85   85   77   77   95   77
   44   44   55   65   65   55   44   44   44   55   65   55   55   44   44   44
   98   77   95   98   98   95   95   77   98   98   98   77   98   95   98   98
   85   85   95   95   77   77   85   77   77   95   95   85   95   85   85   85
   85   77   77   85   95   85   77   65   95   95   85   77   77   77   77   77
   44   55   55   44   44   55   65   65   65   55   44   55   44   44   44   44

Compressed
ans(:,:,1) =

   184   175   159   184   184   175   184   159
   126   150   126   103   126   126   103   103
   184   175   175   150   175   184   184   175
   103   126   126   103   103   126   150   103
   175   184   184   159   159   159   159   150
   103   150   126   103   126   126   103   103
   175   184   159   159   184   175   175   175
   126   103   126   150   126   126   103   103

ans(:,:,2) =

   148   143   132   148   148   143   148   132
    98   116    98    80    98    98    80    80
   148   143   143   116   143   148   148   143
    80    98    98    80    80    98   116    80
   143   148   148   132   132   132   132   116
    80   116    98    80    98    98    80    80
   143   148   132   132   148   143   143   143
    98    80    98   116    98    98    80    80

ans(:,:,3) =

   95   85   77   95   95   85   95   77
   55   65   55   44   55   55   44   44
   95   85   85   65   85   95   95   85
   44   55   55   44   44   55   65   44
   85   95   95   77   77   77   77   65
   44   65   55   44   55   55   44   44
   85   95   77   77   95   85   85   85
   55   44   55   65   55   55   44   44
```

I save this "compressed" matrix to a variable and call imwrite:

```
orig = imread('orig.png')
comp = compress(orig, 1);
imwrite(comp, 'comp.png');
```

And then... imwrite generates a blank image. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

When i imwrite the orig matrix i works properly. But when i try to imwrite the comp matrix i doesn't works

Comment: I am getting an error: `'compress' undefined...`. Can you please post a reference to the documentation or implementation of the function `compress`? What is the `class(comp)`? You may try casting `comp` to `uint8` before saving: `imwrite(uint8(comp), 'comp.png');`

Comment: The class of the variable being saved determines the bit depth of the image written. If comp is of type double or single, it will expect the values to be between 0 and 1.  Anything over 1 will be treated as 1. Likely, this is why you’re seeing a blank image.  Recast your comp as uint8 as Rotem said and it should work.